# systemic absorption of chlorhexidine

Tags: medications, dentistry, research, periodontitis

I have question from dentistry field in Periodontology.

How much is .25%  chlorhexidine gel absorbed in plasma or blood when placed in periodontal pocket ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! What has your research revealed so far? Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @LangLangC FYI research has not yet started . Just need information about this before starting. Do you have any info ?